# Show reader accounts associated with a secure view in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a secure view in Snowflake, let's call it `db.schema.vw_hello_world`. I have shared that view with two different reader accounts, Account_A and Account_B. **Is there SQL syntax in Snowflake to show all of the reader accounts that view is exposed to?**

Input SQL:
something like `show reader_accounts associated with db.schema.vw_hello_world`

output:
`Account_A`
`Account_B`

Answer (score 0):

Such a feature is not available today.
we are not deploying views to an account however, we are adding the views to a share and then granting access to the share. Hence the only way to track the usage is at the share level and not at the object level.

```
SHOW GRANTS OF SHARE <share_name>;
```

This command will let you know the details about the accounts that are using the share